# Extra characters added during string concatenation

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I am working on a C++ code that concatenates values together into a string of chars for an I2C message system. I have the messaging properly worked out, but when I concatenate the strings together, the code incorrectly concatenates more than just the three values I want onto the string. The code I have written is below:

```
void concatint(int value1, char address1, char address2)
{
    int alive1 = static_cast<int>(address1);
    int alive2 = static_cast<int>(address2);
    char* alive3 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(address1));
    char* alive4 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(address2));
    //alive3 = address1;
    //alive4 = address2;
    sprintf(alive3, "%2d", address1);
    sprintf(alive4, "%2d", address2);
    if (value1 < 10)
        readlength = 1;
    if (value1 >= 10 && value1 < 100)
        readlength = 2;
    if (value1 >= 100 && value1 < 1000)
        readlength = 3;
    if (value1 >= 1000 && value1 < 10000)
        readlength = 4;
    if (value1 >= 10000 && value1 < 100000)
        readlength = 5;
    if (value1 >= 100000 && value1 < 1000000)
        readlength = 6;
    if (value1 >= 1000000 && value1 < 10000000)
        readlength = 7;
    if (value1 >= 10000000 && value1 < 100000000)
        readlength = 8;
    *writedata = 0;
    itoa(value1, writedata, 10);
    strcpy(writeaddress, &address1);
    strcat(writeaddress, &address2);
    strcat(writeaddress, writedata);
    strcpy(readaddress, address1);
    strcat(readaddress, address2);
    typevalue = 1;
}
```

This function has the input of:

```
concatint(5, ' ', ' ');
```

where the two address values are two ASCii characters.

The result of this code should be: ' '' '5 with the ASCii characters being concatenated before the value. However, when I run the code, the result I get is:

```
" \005  \0055"
```

My code seems to concatenate an extra character in between my characters and I am not sure where my above code adds that. I've stepped through the code and everything should work fine, not sure where my problem is.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `c++`? This (using cstrings, malloc and cstring functions) is certainly not the way to do this when using `c++`.

Comment: Please just use `std::string`. I beg you.

Comment: What are all the undefined variables you are using? Where are they defined? How are they initialized? Why are you checking such large ranges for `value1` when you know it can't be more than `-128` to `127` (or `0` to `255`, depending on the signedness of `char`)? And lastly, where do you `free` `value3` and `value4`?

Comment: this code is so wrong that its hard to know where to start. What do you think that the first static_cast is doing?

Answer (score 4):

The first eight lines have undefined behaviour:

```
void concatint(int value1, char address1, char address2)
{
    int alive1 = static_cast<int>(address1);
    int alive2 = static_cast<int>(address2);
    // Note that address1 is a char, not a char*, and as such sizeof(address1)
    // is guaranteed to be 1.  Thus we allocate one byte of storage.
    char * alive3 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(address1));
    char * alive4 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(address2));
    // Here we write two digits and a terminating NUL to that one byte
    // => undefined behaviour.  Cannot reason further about the program.
    sprintf(alive3, "%2d", address1);
    sprintf(alive4, "%2d", address2);
```

Furthermore:

```
    strcpy(writeaddress, &address1);
```

won't work either.  `address1` is a single character. `&address1` is a pointer to this character, but there is no trailing NUL character following it, so it is not a valid pointer to pass to `strcpy` either.

Use `std::string`